# Android LiveData after activity resume gets only latest item

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have chat activity. Due to this, I add messages one by one, as I receive them.

I am trying to use ViewModel with Activity. I am using LiveData to pass messages from ViewModel to Activity. Everything works fine when Activity is active, but when Activity is in hidden state my observer not getting items from ViewModel. Also when I resume the activity my observer gets only latest item that was assigned to it in ViewModel.

Basically I need to buffer items if app is in background, and get them all on activity resume.

```
ChatViewModel
class ChatViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var adapterMessagesLive: MutableLiveData<AdapterChatItems> = MutableLiveData()

fun addMessage() {
   adapterMessagesLive.value = AdapterChatItems(items, addDirection)
}

}


ChatActivity
public class ChatActivity implements LifecycleRegistryOwner {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         viewModel.getAdapterMessagesLive().observe(this, adapterChatItemsObserver -> {
               getAdapter().addMessages(adapterChatItemsObserver);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Found out that LiveData has method `hasActiveObservers()`, I will try to use it